# Mail Merge Specific Keywords

Tags: docx4j, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge, docx4j.net

I was wondering if there is some way that mail merge specific keywords such as "*Ask*", "*Fill-in*", "*If Then Else*", etc are being handled in **docx4j**. Here is a full list of keywords that I'm looking to handle in the code.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-the-rules-for-a-mail-merge-d546ee7e-ab7a-4d6d-b488-41f9e4bd1409

Answer (score 1):

These are all round tripped in docx4j's general operation.

However, none of them are handled specifically in docx4j's MailMerge processing code, with the exception of NEXT record.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, Jason. Could you please clarify what you're referring to by the phrase "round tripped"?

Comment: Is there any way to enforce Personally Identifiable Information (PII) functionality with docx4j API such that PII locked fields appear as "****" and not get replaced by their actual key value?

Also, is there a way to process a password protected mail merge template?